# How to get all class methods

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following classes:

```
class DBManagerInterface:

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, table_name): raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def create_table(self): raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def drop_table(self): raise NotImplementedError



class DataBaseManager(DBManagerInterface):

    def __init__(self, table_name):
        self.table_name = table_name

    def drop_table(self):
        None

    def create_table(self):
        None


class Example:

def __init__(self, db_manager):
    self.db_manager = db_manager

def test(self):
    self.db_manager.create_table() # can't see the db_manager methods
```

In `Example` class I'm getting the `DataBaseManager` pointer.

I wan't to be able to see all the `DataBaseManager` methods (without the need to search them manually in `DataBaseManager.py` file)

I'm using `python 3.5.2` and `pycharm` editor

Is it possible ?

Comment: `print( dir(DataBaseManager) )` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm has no idea what `db_manager` could be, so it can't give you edit hints.

If your environment supports it, annotate the argument and PyCharm can do type inference from there:

```
    def __init__(self, db_manager: DBManagerInterface):
        self.db_manager = db_manager
```

or if that's not supported, you can add an annotation in a docstring:

```
    def __init__(self, db_manager):
        """
        :type db_manager: DBManagerInterface
        """
        self.db_manager = db_manager
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not able to see the methods of the DataBaseManager class in the attribute `db_manager` in Example class, is because there is no reason why the variable `db_manager` in the `__init__` method is supposed to be an instance of DataBaseManager.

You can either specify the type directly: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Or you can check the instance type in the `__init__` method:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self, db_manager):
        if not isinstance(db_manager, DataBaseManager):
            raise ValueError
        self.db_manager = db_manager
```

Pycharm will afterwards understand the type of the attribute and show you all the possible methods for the object.

Comment: A forcible `isinstance` breaks duck typing though, so one can't properly test `Example` with e.g. a `unittest.mock`-ed database manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`print(dir(DataBaseManager))`

From the [docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

`dir([object])`